# phundament 3: missing bootstrap top navbar on fresh install

Tags: yii, composer-php, phundament

The top black navbar doesnt show

i made a fresh install : 
composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist phundament/app my-app
(made the virtualhost and rename the htaccess)
i left all the config params as default (sqlite)

All install great, no problem.
But the top  black navbar doesnt show as he had to.

seems to be a css problem but i cant find the solution,
i tried enable de LESS copiler , same result

ideas ?

Screen:
[image: actual navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a css problem. The `navbar` requires an extra class `navbar-inverse` see http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/widgets/navigation/view/navbar.html for more information.

Comment: Should work as described, I just tested it with `'type' => 'inverse'`.